# How to simulate a soft keyboard click on IOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, iphone-softkeyboard

I am using XCTest to test my IOS app.
As part of a test case I need to enter a number into a field (**which is not a text box**)
When I record the test, following code is generated when I use the soft keyboard on the simulator(IPAD/IPhone)

```
app.staticTexts["0"].tap() //Line 1
app.typeText("23")         //Line 2
```

When I execute the test, the soft keyboard pops up after Line 1. But when Line 2 is executed, following error appears

UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus

My app requires to be installed on IPads/IPhones. So I need to make it run through the soft keyboard route only.

So I think typeText is not the correct method. What is the method to simulate clicks on a soft/virtual keyboard in an IOS simulator?﻿

Comment: When `app.staticTexts["0"].tap()` is executed, the soft keyboard pops up. There is no soft keyboard before this line is executed.
Next, if I introduce a breakpoint at Line 2 and intervene manually to click on the soft keyboard, I see the value being entered. That is why I ask if there is a way to simulate a soft keyboard click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `typeText()` on the element with keyboard focus, not just `app`.

If the element was a text field, you would find the text field element and call `typeText()` on that.

```
let element = app.textFields["myTextField"]
element.typeText("23")
```

You will need to replace the query with your own one for finding the element which has keyboard focus. Usually, this would be a descendant of UITextField but you will need to use a more custom query if you are using a custom view instead.